# How to fail Ant build when mvn task fails?

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, maven-ant-tasks

I have an Ant build which calls mvn tasks using "artifact:mvn ..." as described in http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html.

Problem is, even when one of these inner mvn builds ends in FAILURE, my overall Ant build will still report BUILD SUCCESSFUL at the end.

How can I make my Ant build report a build failure when at least one of the mvn tasks fails?

Comment: Did you try to add `failonerror="true"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The [mvn task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html) is a subclass of the Ant [java task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) and supports all of its options

The task may fail right away with `failonerror="true"` or you might verify `resultproperty` later on.

> By default the return code of a `<java>` is ignored. Alternatively, you can set resultproperty to the name of a property and have it assigned to the result code (barring immutability, of course). When you set failonerror="true", the only possible value for resultproperty is 0. Any non-zero response is treated as an error and would mean the build exits.

Comment: Thanks! Adding failonerror="true" did what I wanted it to do!